# Update statement for a regular table has a where clause with a join to the ORACLE_USER table so I get insufficient privileges

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I can update "table1" directly if I don't join it to the Oracle_User table, but once the join is added, I get the insufficient privileges error. I get that it's because the system thinks I'm trying to update the ORACLE_USER table. Is there anyway around this?

```
UPDATE
(
SELECT
  ut.description
FROM
  ifsapp.table1 ut
JOIN IFSAPP.ORACLE_ACCOUNT oa
ON
  oa.USERNAME = ut.ORACLE_USER
JOIN IFSAPP.table2 up
ON
  ut.oracle_user = up.user_name
WHERE
  up.default_value       <> '11'
AND oa.default_tablespace = 'USERS'
AND oa.profile           <> 'INTERNAL'
AND up.entry_code_db      = 'COMPANY'
AND ut.identity LIKE 'A%'
)
T
SET
ut.description = 'First X Last' ;
```

Comment: Can you run the `select` statement for the inline view you're trying to update?  If you're getting a permission issue, I'd wager that you don't have permission to `select` from `oracle_account` (or `table2`).

Comment: I do. Had to make sure my select statement was right before I even attempt to update anything.

Answer (score 0):

Would rewriting it to something like this help?

```
update ifsapp.table1 ut set
  ut.description = 'First X Last'
  where ut.oracle_user = 
  (select up.user_name
   from ifsapp.table2 up join ifsapp.oracle_account oa
     on oa.username = up.user_name
   where up.default_value <> '11'
     and oa.default_tablespace = 'USERS'
     and oa.profile <> 'INTERNAL'
     and up.entry_code_db = 'COMPANY'
  )
    and ut.identity like 'A%';
```

Comment: Same error. I guess I need to use the API.